# Sharepoint 2013 - Analytics - Popularity Trends

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, web-analytics, data

We have been using some of the OOTB analytics such as Popularity Trends and reports. Up till a month ago we were receiving regular reliable data. It suddenly stopped. Where is my first point of call to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of things to check.

- Check the Usage and Health Data service is up and running.
- Proper Events are selected (Analytics Usage, Feature Use, and Page Requests) in the Usage and Health data services.
- Usage Health data service is connected with the web applciation.
- Make sure Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import and Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing timers jobs are running.
- Check the Log folders that proper logs files are being generated.
- Search service is working properly.
- Check the event logs for any clue.

Read more on this 
[Troubleshooting SharePoint 2013 Web Analytics](http://blog.fpweb.net/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2013-web-analytics/#.WQZwB9Lyt3g)

Comment: How about external data? Can i generate similar logs for another non-Sharepoint web apps? By c#., In log folder? The source of reports is log folder? Or mssql table?